# Find set $A$ whose limit points are the same as its boundary points

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was reading a problem that asked to find a non-empty set $A$ such that set of limit points in $A$ is the same as the set of boundary points in $A$.  The solution given was to pick the set of all $x\in\mathbb{R^2}$ such that $|x|=1$.  I was wondering if there are any other such sets $A$?  Below is the problem and solution in case you wanted to see the solution they had.

**Edit**
Also, I'm a bit confused by their solution.  If we were to consider the entire circle, the boundary of the circle would be the outer points.  but since we are only considering those outer points, what are they bounding?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Boundary points do not do any "bounding". The boundary of a subset $A$ of a space $S$ is $\overline A \cap \overline {S\setminus A}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost any curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ will have this property: any conic section, graph of an elementary function, etc. (Every point in the curve is a limit point of the curve, and of its complement)

Comment: you mean $\mathbb{R^2}$, right?  and I'm just confused about the idea of the boundary.  If we consider any appropriate curve in $\mathbb{R^2}$ then why are those points boundary points?

Comment: The boundary is the set of points in both the closure of a set and the closure of its complement. In the case of a curve (unless it's space-filling or otherwise strange), the closure of the curve is the curve itself. On the other hand, there are points arbitrarily close to any point in the curve that are not in the curve.

Answer (score 2):

Another less trivial example is the set of rational numbers.

The set of its boundary points is the set of real numbers which is also the set of its limit points.

Comment: I really like this answer, but I gave the correct answer to the other user because he replied first.  Thanks

Comment: @johnfowles Thanks for the comment. You are the OP and it is your right to accept one solution. It does not mean that other answers are not correct.